# Multithread in NDK on Android5.0 not running?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have created 5 threads in NDK level by using pthread_create(…,…,…).

In my Android APP, when it runs on Android 4.4, every single thread's time 
consuming is 200ms, and total consuming time is also about 200ms. However
when the OS is Android 5.0.2 on the same phone, every single thread's time consuming is 800ms, and the total time is 800ms. It seems the five threads are not in the separate threads.

Comment: I think this situation again.I think my NDK thread application seems share common resourses, and make the situation.Can anyone give me more hits?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121016/ ?