# The efficiency of multiple threads acceleration is quite different in Android 4.4 and 5.0

Tags: android, c, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wrote a fragment of C code to do some image processing (intensive computation) in Android (compiled by NDK and utilized by the jni.h). To accelerate the image processing, I used pthread_create and pthread_join functions in the C code to utilize 4 threads to process the image simultaneously.  The multiple threads acceleration is successful in the Android 4.4 mobile phones but failed in all Android 5.0 mobile phones. 
Suppose that the processing time of image_processing function in a single thread environment is 1s. We utilized 4 threads to accelerate the image_processing function like that:

```
void image_processing_multiply_threads()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t pt[4];
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
    {
       if ( pthread_create(pt + i , NULL, image_processing, (void *)(arg + i)) != 0 )
       {
         return;
       }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       pthread_join(pt[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

In Android 4.4, the processing time of each thread is about 300ms, so the total time of image_processing_multiply_threads is 300ms, in other words, we got 3.3 times acceleration.
But we utilize the same code in the Android 5.0, the processing time of each thread became 1.1s, that means multiple threads version didn’t affect even worse than the one thread version. In Android 5.0, we check the status of each thread. Every thread was successfully created by the pthread_create and the stack size of each thread is same as the size in 4.4. 
We also tested the two mobile phones with same hardware but different OS version, in 4.4 version, the multiple threads code was successful, but in 5.0 failed.
What is the problem in Android 5.0? How can we solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running the different Android versions on *exactly* the same hardware?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Yes, we run the same code on the same hardware but with only different Android OS vesion. The result is same.In 4.4, we got 3.3 times acceleration but it is failed in 5.0

Comment: You may want to run an experiment with systrace. You can find the experiment I performed back on Android 4.3 here: http://bigflake.com/systrace/

Comment: Thanks for your response. The systrace is performed by Dalvik VM. But in Android 5.0, the Dalvik VM is substituted by ART. Can the systrace be run in Android 5.0?